# right way to make a jar file from javafx application

Tags: java

I have a javafx project, which contains multiple paths for images and text files :

```
private Image imgMan = new Image(getClass().getResource("../man.gif").toExternalForm());

FileHelper.resetScores("./bin/application/MAP/BestScores.txt");
```

...

When i launch from eclipse, it work normally, and access to images and files without any problem.

But when i try to export my project to a jar file, it export correctly, but it don't launch !

I try to launch it from cmd, the trace of stack said that he don't know the paths...

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at application.Client.(Client.java:31)

(line 31 in my code refer to the first line of code given in the question)

I try to create a resource folder and put all files into it, but no result.

So what is the best way to make it ?
where must i create the resource folder ?
and how to access the files into it from the code ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several thing you should check:

- verify the path in your jar against the class you are looking. Your image must be there.
- verify you have successfully loaded a resource because using it, eg: check if getResource returns null.

For the first point, it depends on how you build your jar:

- Eclipse will by default copy class file and resources to `bin` unless you use m2e. If you use the *Extract runnable JAR* (from *File > Export* menu), it may ignore some resources.
- If you use Maven then your images must be in `src/main/resources` by default.

For the second point, you should use a method that should check the resource exists before delegating to Image. While it won't change your core problem, you would have a less subtile error:

```
static javafx.scene.image.Image loadImage(Class<?> source, String path) {
  final InputStream is = source.getResourceAsStream(path);
  if (null == is) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not load image from " + source + " path: " + path);
  }
  try (is) { // Java 9 -> you may want to use InputStream is2 = is
    return new javafx.scene.image.Image(is); // use is2 for Java < 9
  }
}
```

You should also try with an absolute path (from the root of the jar, or your `src/main/resources` if you use maven):

```
Image image = loadImage(this.getClass(), "/images/man.gif");
```

Comment: can i use getClass().getResource("../man.gif").toExternalForm() ?

Comment: Not with `getResourceAsStream` (it returns an `InputStream` which will be `null` if resource is not found). You can use it, but that's the same: there is a constructor taking an `InputStream`. And it won't fix your resource being absent from your classpath.

Comment: must i use jar file or runnable jar file ?

Comment: another question : jar file location must not be changed ?

Comment: and where must i install the jar file ?

Comment: For Eclipse, a runnable jar file is simply a JAR with a MANIFEST.MF with a Main-Class attributes. If you want to use getResource on a Class, then you must ensure that the resource you are looking are in the same JAR than the class that is accessing them: open your jar with 7-zip and check its content!

Comment: look in the first page of my app, the image load correctly, but when i click a button, the images in the next page doesn't appear, why ? and thank you

Comment: after "javapackager", i open the jar with winrar, i found only the classes, it don't contain any resources!